# How can I render Map() items into React jsx by forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a Map() object in state and that store some names and options for list filter. but I can't render Map items in JSX by forEach like this :

```html
<ul>
{
    this.state.items.forEach((value, key) => (
        <li>{value}</li>
    ))
}
</ul>
```

Apparently I can't access to Map items without forEach and in this case Array.map() is not usable.

What's the best practice to handle this issue ? I should use entries() and then Array.map() and then render the list ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: **if you cannot use `map`** then use a variable

```
const elems = []
this.state.items.forEach((value, idx) => (
  elems.push(<li key={idx}>{value}</li>)
))
```

then when rendering

```
<ul>
  {elems}
</ul>
```

Option 2: **if you can use `map`** then just do it inline

```
<ul>
  {
    this.state.items.map((value, idx) => <li key={idx}>{value}</li>)
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this the right way ? if first I store the values in external array and then do a map loop on that, in this case I added an additional step and apparently it's not optimized for large size Map

Comment: Huh? you only loop once, either before in an array then you render that array, or you render that array inline via a `map` operator. This is the correct way to do it, and its only looping once.

Comment: if I use that push for elms array, first I've a loop to fill elms and then the second loop for elms.map() to render the list, right ? or I've mistake ?

Comment: No, once you have the array of elems, you can just render it. Although it's not very pretty, this is valid in React: `<ul> {[<li>val1</li>, <li>val2</li>]} </ul>`.

Comment: I got it, when I set an Array.map() to a variable, that returns an array, but if I set that variable to Array.forEach() that returns undefined, weird JavaScript :-)))

Comment: @Alex you should read up on what the different iterators do. A `forEach` loops the elements of an array where you can do something with them. A `map` returns a new array with whatever you want to do with those elements (like transform them). A `filter` returns a new array that is a smaller subset of the first one where you filter elements out of it... etc (many others like `reduce` `sort`). I would **strongly** recommend you read up on what you're using to understand the use cases of each and when to use one

Comment: you should also add a key in each li, when using map is recommended to use a key

Comment: @JohnRuddell right and I see, but in this case I need to store unique keys and handle this loop .... if I use the Array I should write a lot of codes to handle unique keys like set or map with filter and then do a loop with Array.map() to render the list. if I use map to store values, I've an additional array like that elems to push items and I should define that before component  render inside the render and think it's not attractive and maybe it's dirty code ...

Comment: I dont think i understood that, what I just posted is not dirty code though, this is the normal practice for rendering elements from an array.